# how the ratio of two functions change...what am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

For $s \in \{1,\dots,T-2\}$, let $g(s) := \frac{f(s+1)}{f(s+2)} = \frac{\sum_{t=s+1}^{T} \frac{0.99^{t-1}}{1 + \text{exp}\left(\frac{t-1}{3} - 9\right)} \frac{1}{t}}{\sum_{t=s+2}^{T} \frac{0.99^{t-1}}{1 + \text{exp}\left(\frac{t-1}{3} - 9\right)} \frac{1}{t}}$

I need to figure out whether and for which values of $s$, $g(s)$ increases. I thought, ok fine, if between $s$ and $s+1$ the numerator increases more or decreases less than the denominator, then I say that $g(s)$ is increasing for that particular $s$. So, I started to look at the following ratio:

$\frac{f(s+2) - f(s+1)}{f(s+3) - f(s+2)} = \frac{-\frac{0.99^{s}}{1 + \text{exp}\left(\frac{s}{3} - 9\right)} \frac{1}{s+1}}{-\frac{0.99^{s+1}}{1 + \text{exp}\left(\frac{s+1}{3} - 9\right)} \frac{1}{s+2}} = \frac{1 + \text{exp}\left(\frac{s+1}{3} - 9\right)}{1 + \text{exp}\left(\frac{s}{3} - 9\right)} \frac{1}{0.99}\frac{s+2}{s+1} > 1$     for all $s \in \mathbb{N}$

Then, since the numerator decreases more then the denominator my conclusion was that $g(s)$ is decreasing for all relevant values of $s$. I wrote down a small R code plotting $g(s)$ and it looks like $g(s)$ is not even monotone for some values of $T$; I checked the code a couple of times and it still *seems* fine to me. So my question is, is my argument about $g(s)$ incorrect? and if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is right, but in this case you want to consider the *ratio* of the values of $f$ instead of their difference.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was too optimistic thinking I could get rid of the sums